# C#: Working with dynamics where properties' value have unexpected results

Tags: c#, dynamic

The `dynamics` type has been a blessing for me. Receiving responses as a dynamic object and using its properties instead of having to define a model saves so much time. There's only one problem that I've encountered and haven't been able to figure out:

[image: CodeScreenshot]

**What's happening in the above screenshot and what would be the solution?** As you can see, the variable `resultGetBudget` has been correctly inititated and there're values available for the `code` and `current_amount` properties. However, when I try to access these variables some time later, one of them suddenly becomes `null`. Even stranger, when I don't put them in a variable, they're both `null`.

I've researched this issue before and found some *not-always-working workarounds* like [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), as suggested by a Microsoft MVP (can't find the source anymore) but now that I've encountered this for the second time, it's really bothering me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
resultGetBudget?.result.current_amount
```

i think, "current_amount" is inside a "result" array of stuff, "code" works because is outside of it.

thinking about it like a json should be something like that:

```
main_object{
   code:200
   result: {
        start_amount:200
        current_amount:200
        [..... other stuff.....]
   }
}
```

Comment: I... have no idea how I've missed this. I'm doubting my past self and wondering if the same nistake happened earlier (which I don't think it was). Your solution worked out, thank you

Comment: @WouterVanherck You missed it because you used a false blessing... Now you'll spend more time to debug your code, and your code will have a javascript-y feeling, where everything works until it stops working because a single letter has been changed.

Comment: Thinking about it, this human error doesn't explain the fact that if I don't use variables and use the resultGetBudget?.code directly, that its result is still null? I think there's more to my problem than this, even if I have a solution now. Also, I'm fairly sure that in the past, my object was structured like `dynamic obj = new { testVarWithVal, testVarWithoutVal = "test" };` so no arrays or inner objects... Would be nice to know that too.